# Different versions of PSQL when using DTO to get DB's names

Tags: dto, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I am working on an application, installed on windows OS, that connects to a Sage 50 (Peachtree) accounting software.

The connection between the application and Sage is created using ODBC.
To create the ODBC connection I am using the PSQL DTO lib to get the list of available databases. I obtained the lib from the PSQL SDK here - https://esd.actian.com/product/Zen_PSQL.

I wanted to know if i need to worry about different versions of PSQL when using the DTO for the functionality of getting the available databases names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you stick to the the base DTO library (and not DTO2) you should be able to support versions all the way back to PSQL v9 (the first version to support DTO).

Comment: Sounds good! Can you direct me to the best way to get the first DTO version?

Comment: Just make sure you use the "Pervasive Distributed Tuning Library 1.0" and not the "Pervasive Distributed Tuning Library 2.0."  Both should be on your system, if you're running a version that supports the 2.0 library.

Comment: Thank you. In my case i found the files in my Sage accounting system folder -> PervasiveMin > DTO.cab file